# Conditional limit

Tags: math-mode, math-operators

I want to write ``conditional limit'' in math mode, which contains a right arrow, a down arrow and three parameters (the expression tends to A while B goes to C).
I have  tried to solve it with `\mkern`, but it's not the best.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\def\limdownarrow{\qopname\relax m{\downarrow}}

\begin{document}

The expression goes to zero, while $\epsilon$ goes to zero:
$$\lim\limits_{\epsilon\to0} \left( F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \right) = 0$$
Which could be written as:
$$F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \to \mkern-19mu\limdownarrow_0^{\epsilon} 0 $$

\end{document}
```

Creates:

[image: MWE]

Is there any ``bulit-in'' operator for this quest?

Comment: isn't that normally written `.. \xrightarrowp\epsilon\downarrow0]{}  0`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Never seen such a notation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tendstoas}[2]{\mathrel{\tendstoas@{#1}{#2}}}
\newcommand{\tendstoas@}[2]{%
  \mathop{%
    \vphantom{\big\downarrow}%
    \ooalign{$\m@th\longrightarrow$\cr\hfil$\m@th\big\downarrow$\hfil}%
  }\limits^{#1}_{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

The expression goes to zero, while $\epsilon$ goes to zero:
\[
\lim_{\epsilon\to0} \left( F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \right) = 0
\]
Which could be written as:
\[
F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \tendstoas{\epsilon}{0} 0
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes: `\limits` is redundant in display math mode; `$$` should never be used in LaTeX.

Alternatives:

```
Which could be written as:
\[
F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \xrightarrow[\epsilon\to0]{} 0
\]
Which could be written as:
\[
F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \xrightarrow{\epsilon\to0} 0
\]
```

[image]

Following the suggestion of Sebastiano to use a symbol from the STIX2 fonts, namely `\tosa` ⤩, but rotating it 45 degrees, here's a variant:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{stix2sf}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{stix2sf}{m}{it}{<-> stix2-mathsfit}{}
\newcommand{\tendstoas}[2]{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathop{%
      \rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\usefont{U}{stix2sf}{m}{it}\symbol{"C2}}%
    }\limits^{#1}_{#2}%
  }%
}
```

[image]

Comment: There is in `stix` font also the specific symbols; `U+2927 \tona∗
⤨ U+2928 \toea∗
⤩ U+2929 \tosa∗
⤪ U+292A \towa∗`. Is it possible to see, for comparison, rotating one of this symbol the output and declare just only one symbol?

Comment: @Sebastiano The arrowheads are quite different, though.

Comment: With all the sincerity of this world when I think of the hooked tips of arrows (e.g. xy package) I always think of you :-) and I smile. Ok and thanks for your feedback. I had already voted before. All the best.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\condlimit[2]{\mathrel{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{-1.7pt}{c}{-.4pt}{\mathop{\downarrow}\limits^{#1}_{#2}}%
  {\rightarrow}}}}
\begin{document}
\[
1 + F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon)\condlimit{0}{\epsilon} 1
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

```
\newbox\xtobox
\setbox\xtobox=\hbox{\mathsurround=0pt$\longrightarrow$}
\setbox\xtobox=\hbox to\wd\xtobox{\rlap{\box\xtobox}\hss\lower.2ex\hbox{$\downarrow$}\hss}
\def\xto#1#2{\mathop{\copy\xtobox}\limits_{#1}^{#2}}

test:
$F(x+\epsilon) - F(x-\epsilon) \xto{\epsilon}{0} 0$
```

Differences from egregs solution: (1) The vertical arrow is not `\big` but it is smaller and lowered. This takes less vertical space in the math formula. (2) The operator box is pre-calculated in the preamble of the document, not calculated in every usage.

Comment: The construction should be a `\mathrel`, in my opinion, to get the right spacing. Using a prebuilt box won’t work if the object is used in a `\footnotesize` context.